# Can't import Android project into Eclipse - Finish button doesn't do anything

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I have downloaded latest ActionBarSherlock and trying to open it in Eclipse.

[image]

After pressing Finish button nothing happens.
No errors.
All buttons work as if I have not pressed Finish button. I can return Back or Refresh or check checkbox.

My path has no spaces.

ActionCarSherlock requires ADT version 0.9.7 but I have found following version of software in eclipse.

Android Development Tools 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group   The Android Open Source Project

**PS Eclipse update has not helped me (updating SDK)**

**PS Android SDK update fixed it**

Comment: I guess its some sort of Eclipse or ADT problem not ActionBarSherLock Problem.

Comment: Yes. At least Eclipse must tell what s wrong. There is no error. It is not first time I import project. I have many imported projects like ad networks or video codec libs for android. It always worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I came across this problem yesterday.

I had recently updated the ADT plugin without updating the Android SDK Tools and Platform-tools.

So make sure all of the above are up-to-date.

Comment: This ended up being an updating problem for me too as Benito suggested. This helped https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Make sure you have at least one SDK / API Level installed

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your ADT (21.1.0) and install your ADT to 23.0.2.

Some features that will apply in the last version isn't compatible with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seemed Finish did nothing, but my Project Explorer view wasn't open. You have to click on the small icon to have the Project Explorer open.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SEsc.png

Comment: The finish button must have still made the dialogue go away in your case. Your solution seems to be for a completely different problem with different symptoms

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is because your imported project is in the same directory of your workspace directory. If you move the project to an temporary directory and import it with copy box checked, it will copy the project from your temporary directory to your workspace. Then you just delete the temporary directory.